# WARNING: The "Default" Configuration may not build because it uses the "Cygwin GCC" tool-chain that is unsupported on this system

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, cocos2d-x

I am working on cocos2dx in Eclipse and I see the following error when I set cygwin as toolchain.

```
**** WARNING: The "Default" Configuration may not build ****
**** because it uses the "Cygwin GCC" **** 
**** tool-chain that is unsupported on this system. ****
```

In case of updating cygwin, how should I update it and what components should it contain? I cannot run program "make", Launching failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\*\*\*\* Build of configuration Default for project HelloWorld \*\*\*\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795506/build-of-configuration-default-for-project-helloworld)

Comment: Sounds like you're out of luck here (unsupported on this system). You might want to take this to the cocos2d-x forum.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I figured out the solution.
I didnt download couple of cygwin packages gcc and gdb.
Downloading these packages and run afterwards but it produced a new error that states about ":" which cant be used but that error was also dealt with ease courtesy another post on stackoverflow